# log4j.ConfigurationFile configuration in ant build for jetty

Tags: ant, log4j, jetty, log4j2

We trigger jetty through ant target as below

```xml
<target name="jettysh" depends="init">
  <exec executable="${JETTY_HOME}/bin/jetty.sh" failonerror="true">
    <env key="JAVA_OPTIONS"
         value="-server -d64 ${x} ${y} ${z} ${l} -Dsettings.path=${p.path} -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///${dpath}/conf/sample.xml -Djetty.secure.port=${JETTY_SECURE_PORT} -Dapp.dir=${app.dir}"/>
  </exec>
</target>
```

In this we pass **-Dlog4j.configuration** path in the older log4j 1.X version as we are migrating to newer version we are passing the new configuration  **-Dlog4j2.configurationFile**  but the logs are not getting generated .

And also we are not seeing any log files getting generated that means that log configuration itself is not picked
Help is very much appreciated as it is a time bound one.

Answer (score 0):

Jetty Hightide 7.x does not have support for log4j2 at the server level.

Using that ancient EOL version of Jetty, you only have support for log4j2 within your webapps.

That means you have to put the log4j2 jars and it's configuration files in your WAR file.